# VTE Escapes Sequences

Tags: linux, escape-sequences

I'm investigating a problem where messages like

```
]777;notify;Command completed;uname⏎
```

show up in Terminal after executing `uname`. This is not limited to `uname`, this is only an example. I boiled it down to VTE Escape Sequences not properly passed to VTE oder ignored by it.

My question: Where can I find an exhaustive listing of escape sequences that GNOME VTE implements?

Comment: Were you able to identify the cause for this?

Comment: It was an update to my shell that was influenced by a custom patched vte library. It has been reverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It [seems that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Terminal#cite_note-manual-3) *"GNOME Terminal allows the user specify which control character or escape sequence the delete and the backspace keys should generate"* compatible with the ANSI standards.

This point to the [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) of whom you can find a nice list, for example, in the page [ANSI Escape sequences (ANSI Escape codes)](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) of ascii-table.com.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Thing is I can't figure out why it passes ESC] to the terminal instead of parsing it.